# Como posso Criar uma coluna no SQL SERVER onde, dependendo do valor, apareça débito ou crédito?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, asp.net

Boas Amigos, Fiz um programa onde importo dados de um ficheiro excel na base de dados do sql, essa base de dados é sobre valores, e etc...
E queria Saber se tem como criar uma coluna onde depois de ser importado o sql, automaticamente, escreva na coluna ao lado se é débito ou crédito
Exmp:

```
Data Mov    Valor em EUR   Débito/Crédito
23-10-2019    -5000.00     Débito
3-1-2016      1234.50      Crédito
```

Tenho que programar isso no asp.net ou dá para fazer isso no sql? Toda vez que importo naquela tabela me dá o debito e o credito

Codigo asp.net:

```
 protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            String strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
            string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HRD=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", excelConnection);
            excelConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", strConnection);
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
            {
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Dados";
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Mov", "Data Mov.");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Valor", "Data Valor");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Descrição do Movimento" , "Descrição do Movimento");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Valor em EUR", "Valor em EUR");
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
             }
             excelConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Ser possivel é mais existe n maneiras de abordar este assunto, parece me um pouco ampla esta pergunta.

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Como por exemplo?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/cac57b8b-4175-4e59-ab19-efaf4dddaf18/c-serialize-deserialize-tofrom-excel-sheet?forum=vsto @Pedro Pereira

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Então tenho de programar no asp.net certo? O problema é que eu sou novo nisto não sei por onde se quer começar

Comment: Pelo que eu percebi, precisas de importar dos dados do excel usando o asp.net e depois queres armazenar esses dados na base de dados, então vais ter de arranjar foirma de obteres esses dados do ficheiro e colocar numa tablela da base de dados.@Pedro Pereira

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017 coluna virtual pelo que entendi , use um CASE

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Eu já fiz isso... Eu queria agora fazer com que depois de importar os dados na base de dados, na base de dados apareça uma tabela a dizer se o valor que foi improtado na coluna "Valor em EUR" é débito ou crédito

Comment: então já tens o dados importados do lado do c# e queres escrever na base de dados? @Pedro Pereira

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Eu quero que depois de isso, Já na base de dados, o SQL sozinho faça uma lista dos valores que são debitos(negativos) e créditos (positivos)

Comment: desculpa @PedroPereira ainda me parece um pouco vasto, mas podes fazer isso do lado do c# e projectas esses valores na tabela. Se a tabela não esta criada crias primeiro. Mas e se a tabela foi para criar dinamicamente tens de fazer isso do lado do onde pedes para por meio do  c# a criação da tabela ao sql e depois colocas os dados nessa tabela

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Isto é para um cliente, ele simplesmente importa para a base de dados e depois é adicionada  na base de dados uma coluna a dizer se aquele valor é um crédito ou débito... Não dá para explicar melhor que isso... Eu fiz um exemplo e tudo lá em cima

Comment: @PedroPereira string valor =   valor > 0? "Crédito" : "Débito"; string st = "update Dados set Data_Valor = " +  valor where costumizado.tabela_nome;   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246182/sql-update-statement-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já consegui, Eis a Solução pessoal:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Dados ADD [Debito/Credito] AS CASE WHEN [Valor em EUR] < 0 THEN 'Debito' ELSE 'Credito' END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso da para resolver no c#:

```
valor > 0? "Crédito" : "Débito"
```

e essa coluna "Crédito/Débito" no banco de dados nao é necessaria pq é redundante, ao menos que vc tenha debito positivo e credito negativo.

Comment: Onde devo inserir isso no meu código @HudsonPH

Comment: O código está acima

Comment: @PedroPereira como eu disse vc nao precisa salvar credito ou debito no banco de dados pq 'e redundante, o melhor mesmo 'e quando vc faz a leitura pelo c# vc inserir essa marcacao

Comment: ate mesmo um simples sql da para separar credito e debito, select * from nomdatabela where valor > 0

Comment: Mas onde é que eu tenho de inserir essa marcação? em que parte do código? tenho que abrir algum If ou assim?

Comment: Eu Sei que com um sql query, mas eu quero que seja o programa afazer para ser mais facil para o utilizador

Comment: posta o seu codigo de leitura do banco de dados, que eu te ajudo

Comment: O código todo está lá em cima, eu editei á pouco tempo

Comment: Espero que me consiga ajudar :D Não consigo encontrar nada na internet

Comment: @PedroPereira Desculpa mas eu ainda acho que a pergunta está um pouco ampla seria possivel fornecer um pouco de mais detalhes pelo menos eu estou ainda com alguma dificuldade em entender a pergunta

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Isto é para um cliente, e o tipo de tabela que ele tem é de faturas e movimentos e valores, e como é para um cliente eu tenho que fazer o mais otimizado possivel, e ele não tem colunas onde diga débito ou credito... Nem vai pôr porque não é o trabahlo dele... Eu simplesmente vou fzer lhe um programa que 1. Importe ficheiros excel para a base de dados. Feito 2. Que crie uma coluna no momento do upload para que na base de dados seja criada uma coluna a dizer se o valor refere se a um débito ou crédito.. Melhor que isto é impossivel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246182/sql-update-statement-in-c-sharp

Comment: @PedroPereira Pode usar isso para actualizar o campo

Comment: @PedroPereira depois de o campo existir inseres usando essa class que deixei o link acima, pode existir outras soluções mas foi a minha ideia